# VBA Decimal point from float value in a Cell is automatically discarded

Tags: vba, excel

I have a variable with float value i.e.

```
Dim H_reqquant As Double 'Its value is 10.5
```

But when I get this value in VBA like this:

```
H_reqquant = Worksheets("Data").Cells(3, 8).value
```

It is converted from **10.5** to **105**

Any suggestions?

-Hansen

Comment: Have you tried an explicit cast with `CDbl()` ?

Comment: I tried it but the result was same.
Now I have found that if put 10,5 in the cell and get this value in VBA code then I get as 10,5

Comment: So I was wondering if it is due to language settings as I have to set of languages enabled i.e.
English
Danish

Comment: Yeah, that's it. For me (France), comma are working but dot don't.

Comment: Okays thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: Do you know if we can change this behavior in Excel settings ??

Comment: [Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/switch-between-different-languages-by-setting-the-proofing-language-HA010354272.aspx#_Toc254701044)

Comment: @AdrienLacroix I tried to change language settings but it didn't help. Still it accepts Comma instead of Dot..

Comment: And do you really need dot ? Since it's recognized as double with comma, you can do your things, no ?

Comment: I REALLY need dot as its the requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your quick feedbacks
I have fixed it by replacing the Dot in string to Comma and then converting it to double and performing calculations and then writing back to cell as a string :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the value in cells(3,8) is 10.5 and not 105 but formatted to look like 10.5?  Check the formula bar to make sure.

Comment: Well I am sure about it. Before posting here I have debugged it and verified that input values in the cell are correct.

Comment: Can you upload the spreadsheet somewhere and I'll have a look.  It does sound v.weird.

Comment: Do you have an email ? I can send you as an attachment

Comment: I'll get a million spams if it goes up here.  Try http://www.filedropper.com/?r=t and post the link up here

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies. But I have found that it was due to language settings that are set to Danish in my system.

Comment: I've changed the language settings but still unable to fix it.. so now I've uploaded the file here

http://www.filedropper.com/book2_3

Comment: Well, it works fine for me (getting 10.5).  As mentioned earlier, must be to do with languages/locale.

Comment: Thanks for your quick feedbacks
I have fixed it by replacing the Dot in string to Comma and then converting it to double and performing calculations and then writing back to cell as a string :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're pointing at the correct cell?

Try Debug.Print Worksheets("Data").Cells(3, 8).Address

To get the location of the cell you think contains 10.5.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that your locale is set to interpret periods in numbers as commas. In England we have 1,234.56 but other locales have 1.234,56

Comment: Thanks for your quick feedbacks !!!
I have fixed it by replacing the Dot in string to Comma and then converting it to double and performing calculations and then writing back to cell as a string :)

Comment: I was thinking about this a little more; if you use Debug.Print Worksheets("Data").Cells(3, 8).Formula then I think you will always get the correct answer since .Formula overrides any locale settings you might have. It saves you messing about with replacements which will not be portable to other Excel users.